# Want to Retrieve Xpath of Given WebElement using selenium / Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to retrieve XPath of an element using python - selenium. I know the class name for elements and there are multiple elements with same classnames.

Comment: You need to be more specific if you want help. For starters, please refer to the Selenium Python Bindings documentation. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html. It will show you how xpaths work, and should be formed.

Comment: just show your HTML and element to find. we are happy to help you!

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to find the xpath given the class name using Selenium. I've looked for a Selenium WebElement "parent" attribute or getter, and haven't found one suitable for this. My best guess is to use Selenium to [execute some JavaScript](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) to construct/find the xpath of the element given its class name.